# Bare bones servlet application, where to store config settings that I can reference?

Tags: java, servlets

I have a bare bones servlet application.

Do I store config related information in my web.xml file?

Is there an event that fires in my servlet that I should save the config value to to a static readonly variable?

I have a single servlet right now, but is there another file where the lifecycle begins at a global level?

Like in .net, you have your pages, but there is a global.asax.cs class that fires at specific events like:

```
application_startup
application_shutdown
application_beginRequest
application_endRequest
```

Does servlets have this, or is it on a per-servlet basis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
application_startup
application_shutdown
```

Implement [`ServletContextListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html).

```
@WebListener
public class ApplicationListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // Do your job here on application startup.
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // Do your job here on application shutdown.
    }

}
```

You can store application wide variables as an attribute of the [`ServletContext`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html).

```
event.getServletContext().setAttribute("foo" new Foo());
```

It's available in servlets by the inherited `getServletContext()` method.

```
Foo foo = (Foo) getServletContext().getAttribute("foo");
```

And in JSPs by just EL.

```
${foo.someProperty}
```

---

```
application_beginRequest
application_endRequest
```

Implement [`ServletRequestListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequestListener.html):

```
@WebListener
public class RequestListener implements ServletRequestListener {

    @Override
    public void requestInitialized(ServletRequestEvent event) {
        // Do your job here on request begin.
    }

    @Override
    public void requestDestroyed(ServletRequestEvent event) {
        // Do your job here on request end.
    }

}
```

You can store request wide variables as an attribute of the [`ServletRequest`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html).

```
event.getServletRequest().setAttribute("foo" new Foo());
```

It's available in servlets by the passed-in `HttpServletRequest` argument.

```
Foo foo = (Foo) request.getAttribute("foo");
```

And in JSPs by just EL.

```
${foo.someProperty}
```

---

You can even implement the both interfaces in a single class:

```
@WebListener
public class GlobalListener implements ServletContextListener, ServletRequestListener {
    // ...
}
```

Or, more common, for sure if you want to be able to modify/control requests more globally, a [`Filter`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html):

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns={"/some/*"})
public class SomeFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
        // Do here your application startup job.

        // If you have any <init-param> in web.xml, then you could get them
        // here by config.getInitParameter("name") and assign it as field.
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // Do here your request/response preprocessing job.

        // Continue the request/response (if you haven't already forwarded/redirected the request/response beforehand).
        chain.doFilter(request, response);

        // Do here your request/response postprocessing job.
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // Do here your application shutdown job.

        // If you have assigned any expensive resources as field of
        // this Filter class, then you could clean/close them here.
    }

}
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info.

All other listeners of the Servlet API can be found as interfaces in [the `javax.servlet` package](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/package-summary.html). Learn to find your way in the Javadocs.

Comment: and these have to be wired up in the web.xml right? perfect thanks!

Comment: No, not if you're using a Servlet 3.0 compatible container. Note the `@WebListener` and `@WebFilter` annotations. They removes the XML pain. Just putting those classes in the classpath the usual way is more than sufficient. But if you're still on Servlet 2.5 or older, then you really need to bite in the XML, yes. Look at `<listener>` and `<filter>`/`<filter-mapping>` respectively. See also the servlet filters wiki page which I linked near the bottom of my answer (and if you're interested, also the servlets wiki http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

Comment: would you still use these 'raw' filters when using something like spring?  or does spring wrap these somehow an doing this may conflict?  I'm guessing no since under the hood spring is just servlets...

Comment: When you said "Spring", don't you actually mean "Spring MVC"? In that case, you can use it with any servlet based MVC framework, yes. It shouldn't conflict. It's however true that the MVC framework in question may offer replacements/alternatives to filters. Spring MVC for example has the concept of "Interceptors" for this. JSF for example has "Phase listeners" and "System event listeners". They allow you more fine grained control over or based on the lifecycle of the MVC framework used.

Answer (score 2):

For `application_startup` and `application_shutdown` check out [javax.servlet.ServletContextListener](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/Servlets4.html).

For `application_beginRequest` and `application_endRequest`check out [javax.servlet.Filter](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html).

Both enable you to manage a scope (in the form of a map or initalization parameters) where you can put your configuration and/or initialize/finalize components, through the corresponding level events.

Answer (score 0):

Servlets have a load order; it used to bee typical to have a startup servlet that performed initialization tasks, loaded before other servlets.

Nowadays this is usually handled by a startup listener.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14017/filters.htm#i1000654

You *may* store parameters in init-params, but there are other options like JNDI, property files, etc.